# echo $shell not returning anything

Tags: command-line, putty

Trying to identify the path to the default shell in my environment, using:

```
echo $shell
```

However, when I run this, I get a blank response. The system runs for about 5 seconds, then returns nothing in the next line, followed by the command prompt again.

Any ideas what this means, and how do I find the path?

BTW, there is meant to be a path visible if I type that command.

**Edit:**
Tried `echo $SHELL` and got the same response from the system.

Comment: It is `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried it, but still got a blank response. Will edit above as well

Comment: What kind of system is it? What does `grep $USER /etc/passwd` produce?

Comment: @vidarlo Clauric:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/Clauric:/bin/bash

Comment: Try either `printf $PATH` or `printf $SHELL`.  Maybe something wrong with the `echo` command.

Comment: @Terrance: Seem to produce the same answer, except slightly longer, as grep $USER /etc/passwd.

Comment: Does it really take five seconds to execute `echo $shell`? Can you run `time echo $shell`?

Comment: Try reboot and then `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Rebooted and worked fine. No idea what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to read "shell" directly from passwd file:

```
echo $( getent passwd "${USER}" | cut -d: -f7 )
```